# Get tapped word in a UITextview

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have added a uitextview which is initially non editable. I added a tap gesture which enable the editing to true. In the tap gesture selector I get the word that is being tapped. I have tried a lot many solution but none worked for me as a complete solution. Every solution worked if the textview is not scrolled. But if I scroll the textview the exact word is not retrieved. Here is my code for getting the tapped word:

```
 @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    notesTextView.isEditable = true
    notesTextView.textColor = UIColor.white

    if let textView = sender.view as? UITextView {

        var pointOfTap = sender.location(in: textView)
        print("x:\(pointOfTap.x) , y:\(pointOfTap.y)")

        let contentOffsetY = textView.contentOffset.y
        pointOfTap.y += contentOffsetY
        print("x:\(pointOfTap.x) , y:\(pointOfTap.y)")
        word(atPosition: pointOfTap)

 }

func word(atPosition: CGPoint) -> String? {
    if let tapPosition = notesTextView.closestPosition(to: atPosition) {
        if let textRange = notesTextView.tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(tapPosition , with: .word, inDirection: 1) {
            let tappedWord = notesTextView.text(in: textRange)
            print("Word: \(tappedWord)" ?? "")
            return tappedWord
        }
        return nil
    }
    return nil
}
```

## EDITED:

Here is the demo project with the problem.
https://github.com/amrit42087/TextViewDemo

Comment: I think `textView.contentOffset.y` should be `textView.scrollView.contentOffset.y` just give a try...

Comment: No that won't fix. Actually the issue arises when the text has empty lines in between the text. I mean when there is a nextLine character.

Comment: You said it works if not scrolled, know only if there are blank lines? Can you edit the question accordingly?

Comment: sample project would be great help

Answer (score 6):

The best and easiest way in Swift 4

**METHOD 1:**

**Step 1: Add Tap Gesture on the textview**

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapResponse(recognizer:)))

textViewTC.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

**Step 2: Implement Tap Gesture**

```
@objc func tapResponse(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location: CGPoint = recognizer.location(in: textViewTC)
        let position: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: location.x, y: location.y)
        let tapPosition: UITextPosition = textViewTC.closestPosition(to: position)!
        guard let textRange: UITextRange = textViewTC.tokenizer.rangeEnclosingPosition(tapPosition, with: UITextGranularity.word, inDirection: 1) else {return}

        let tappedWord: String = textViewTC.text(in: textRange) ?? ""
        print("tapped word ->", tappedWord)
    }
```

And yes thats it. Go for it.

**METHOD 2:**

The alternate way is that you can enable links for textview and then set the same as an attribute. Here is an example

```
var foundRange = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: "Terms of Use") //mention the parts of the attributed text you want to tap and get an custom action
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link, value: termsAndConditionsURL, range: foundRange)
```

set this attribute text to Textview and `textView.delegate = self`

Now you just need to handle the response in

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
```

Hope it helps you. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add the content offset of the text view. When you convert location into a scrollview it will already take its content offset into account.

Removing:

```
let contentOffsetY = textView.contentOffset.y
pointOfTap.y += contentOffsetY
```

should work.

Comment: I removed it. It works until there is no new line in the text. If there is a new line in the text then the word is not accurate after scrolling the textview a bit below.

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by new line. The code I’m using is here: https://gist.github.com/bgayman/1cd0ade8d14b074f220a6242a088271e I added an empty line of text and it still seemed to work, perhaps you can see what’s different. In general, I think word represent fairly small touch targets so if you’re not getting the exact word, but one adjacent I would say the problem is with the interface and not the code.

Comment: Yes you are right. I am talking about the empty line that you added. The difference is you are trying in a playground. Try it in an actual viewcontroller with a textview in it. Scroll the textview and tap any word in the last para. The word is not the one that is tapped.

Comment: I have added a demo project with the problem. Can you please help me out with it?

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This

```
//add UITextViewDelegate 

    let termsAndConditionsURL = "someText"
        let privacyURL = "SampleText"

        @IBOutlet weak var terms: UITextView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            self.terms.delegate = self

    // Adding Attributed text to TextView

            let str = "By registering, you agree to the Terms and the User Privacy Statement."
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)
            var foundRange = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: "Terms")
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: foundRange)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle , value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: foundRange)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link, value: termsAndConditionsURL, range: foundRange)
            foundRange = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: "User Privacy Statement")
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: foundRange)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.underlineStyle , value: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue, range: foundRange)
            attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.link, value: privacyURL, range: foundRange)
            terms.attributedText = attributedString
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }


     func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool
        {
            if (URL.absoluteString == termsAndConditionsURL)
            {
    // Perform Terms Action here
            } else if (URL.absoluteString == privacyURL)
            {
    // Perform Terms Action here

            }
            return false
        }
```

Comment: My code is already correct. It works well if I use it for a new project or in a new controller. But it doesn't work with the existing project as there might be some problem with the constraints. I have attached the code above. Will be happy if you could check it out once and figure out the problem.